# How to install XVim

Tags: installation, vim

I'm attempting to install XVim on my MacBook. According to [XVim.org](http://xvim.org/), the first step is to checkout XVim, using

```
git clone git@github.com:XVimProject/XVim.git
```

in my terminal. But when I put this in my terminal, I get the error

> Cloning into 'XVim'...
>   git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). 
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.